# Is there a better way to implement forms than using RenderAction?

Tags: model-view-controller, forms, redirect, renderaction

I am working on a .Net MVC2 project where I am trying to modularize functionality as much as possible. One aspect of this would be to place a form in a partial views which is then called using RenderAction. This is so that the form's GET, POST, validation and redirection can be handled independently of the parent view.

I have read blogs and forums etc that suggest that this is not ideal behaviour for MVC, however I cannot think of a way round it. The main issue I am having is redirecting from the rendered action and I understand why I cannot do this.

What I need to know is this: if I can't and shouldn't code my modules in this way, how should I code them so they are independent of the parent view?

Comment: Digbyswift, did you find a workaround? Ive met the same problem and need a solution :-).

Comment: Yes and no :) In the end I thought, since you can only post one form on a page at a time, I didn't see any issue in hard-coding a Response.Redirect into the RenderAction's HttpPost action. An  alternative was to use ActionFilters, i.e. place a filter on the action that controlled the redirection but this seemed like it was over-engineering the solution if a Response.Redirect worked.